# Update Database from single inputs and with multiple checkbox select form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

Is it possible to update a database using a form that has multiple single inputs and then a multi checkbox select from the same form?

I have a form where the client selects his:
a. location; 
b. the date he wants to transfer employees; 
c. CHECKBOX group with multiple employees (from which he selects one or more employees); 
d. the reason for the transfer.

Now, using the above info, a. b. and d. must be written into the database for each c. selected

If I choose only one employee, the data writes into the database correctly, my problem is when more than one is selected.

I will give code if needed, but if this is possible, there should be a standard way of doing this.

The code as follows:

```
     <?php
    session_start(); 
    $old_jc_code = $_SESSION['empl_jc_code'];
    ?>
    <?php
    $new_jc_code = "$_POST[new_jc_code]";
    $move_date = "$_POST[move_date]";
    $move_reason = "$_POST[move_reason]";
    $test = implode(',',$_POST[empl_idno]);    //this is the array from the checkbox select
    ?>
    <?php
    include("../xxx");
        $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
            or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
        $query = "INSERT INTO `empl_movement`  
             (`empl_idno`, `empl_jc_code`, `new_jc_code`, `move_date`, `move_receipt_date`, `move_reason`)
            VALUES 
             ('$test','$old_jc_code','$new_jc_code','$move_date','$move_receipt_date','$move_reason')";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
            or die ("Couldn't execute query. "
                .mysqli_error($cxn));
    ?>
```

Comment: usually i serialize the data then write into db

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. An example of your code would brighten it up.

Comment: You're actually describing the standard way yourself: foreach(c){INSERT a,b,c,d} (no code, just a description). Another way would be a bulk insertion, where you just collect the values in the loop and insert them in your DB with one single Statement. Are you actually getting all the selected Cs? Otherwise I don't see the problem.

Comment: @bouscher I think you have a point there, can you have look at my code and elaborate you statement: foreach(c){INSERT a,b,c,d}

Comment: I have tried this, but it is giving me the error: Couldn't execute query. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: <?php
include("../xxx");
 $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
  or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
 $query = "INSERT INTO `empl_movement`  
    (`empl_idno`, `empl_jc_code`, `new_jc_code`, `move_date`, `move_receipt_date`, `move_reason`)
    VALUES (";
    foreach($empl_idno as $empldata)
    {
     $query .= "'$empl_idno', '$empl_jc_code', '$new_jc_code', '$move_date', '$move_receipt_date', '$move_reason'";
    }
 $query .= ")";
 $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
  or die ("Couldn't execute query. "
   .mysqli_error($cxn));
?>

Comment: @JJMorgan You are now missing the foreach and are doing neither bulk insert nor inserting in the loop. I'll post an answer, give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your above code. Please read the comments. You didn't ask for it, but I use prepared statements in my example, because it is considered good practice and avoids the threat of SQL injection, which your code contained (raw insertion of unvalidated user data into the DB). Also I found your usage of single and double quotes a little messy. Untested!:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$old_jc_code = $_SESSION['empl_jc_code'];
?>
<?php
$new_jc_code = $_POST['new_jc_code'];
$move_date = $_POST['move_date'];
$move_reason = $_POST['move_reason'];
$move_receipt_date=$_POST['move_receipt_date']; //You seem to have forgotten this
$test = $_POST['empl_idno'];    //<- make sure that this is actually an array
?>
<?php
include("../xxx");
    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
        or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
$insData['oldjccode']=$old_jc_code;
$insData['newjccode']=$new_jc_code;
$insData['movedate']=$move_date;
$insData['movereceiptdate']=$move_receipt_date;
$insData['movereceiptdate']=$move_reason;
foreach($test as $testdata){
    $insStrng[]='(?,:oldjccode,:newjccode,:movedate,:movereceiptdate,:movereason)'; //Using prepared statements decreases SQL Injection Threat
    $insData[]=$testdata;

}


$query =  "INSERT INTO `empl_movement`(`empl_idno`, `empl_jc_code`, `new_jc_code`, `move_date`, `move_receipt_date`, `move_reason`) VALUES";
$query .=implode(',',$insStrng);
$statement = $cxn->prepare($query); //preparing the statement with the placeholders
$statement->execute($insData); //inserting the actual data into the placeholders


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be best to recognize if there is one user or many. I do not know how you code look like, but $_POST['employees'] will be an array probably, if this is multiselect field

```
$sql = "UPDATE [your_table] SET [values you want to set] WHERE ";
if(isset($_POST['employees'][1])) // if key 0 is set and 1 is not set then it will be one employeeonly, if key 1 is set then it will be more that one employee
{
  $employees = "`".implode ("`, `", $_POST['employees'])."`";
  $sql  .= "`employee` IN ($employees)";
}
else
{
  $employees = $_POST['employees'][0];
  $sql  .= "`employee` = `$employees`";
}
```